# Comments route in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create Comments on User created Articles in Rails 5.1.
After a Comment is submitted, the redirect should be to the '/articles/:id' but is instead redirecting to '/articles/:id/comments'.

I'm using nested routing in routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
  root to: "articles#index"

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

My CommentsController.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article

  def create
    unless current_user
      flash[:alert] = "Please sign in or sign up first"
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      @comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user

      if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created"
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Comment not created correctly"
      end
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

The form for Comments in articles/show.html.erb:

```
<!--Start of comments-->
<div class="col-md-12">
  <%= form_for [@article, @comment],
               :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} do 
                  |f| %>
    <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
     <div class="panel panel-danger col-md-offset-1">
       <div class="panel-heading">
         <h2 class="panel-title">
           <%= pluralize(@comment.error.count, "error") %>
           prohibited this comment from being saved:
         </h2>
         <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-md-2">
        <%= f.label :body, 'New Comment' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
       <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: "form-control", placeholder: "New Comment" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

How do I make this submit button save and redirect back to 'articles/:id'? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know, because that redirect statement should work.  I do notice the code `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` but the `:id` in the CommentsController should be the `id` of a Comment object.  The article should be `params[:article_id]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes generated by in your router will look something like this:

```
/articles/:article_id/comments/:id
```

This means, when you need to load your article in the CommentsController, you should do something like this (as suggested by @Marlin):

```
def set_article
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
end
```

Otherwise, you run the risk of attaching the comment to the incorrect article if there happens to be an ID collision between the IDs in the comments and article table. Or you simply get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

But I know, that this doesn't answer your question directly, ut I suspect that the issue is that you're loading the wrong record from the db somewhere because of the above mentioned.

Try updating your code, and write a test, to make sure that you can programmatically reproduce the error :)

Comment: Thank you both! Changing that line in set_article changed the entire functionality. Lesson learned.

Comment: @Phil, all the routes behaves like this, the parenting IDs will be named according to the route. Otherwise rails has no way of knowing which ID is which. You can always view your routes by running `rake routes` in your console.